# “There have been many inventions” Is this Present Perfect Continuous?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

I'm uncertain whether this sentence is in the active or passive voice.

> “There have been many inventions”

Can someone help to understand the grammar behind this? If it is passive, I'm expecting the PP or the verb. If it is present perfect continuous, then, it should have the suffix '-ing'.

> In the past 100 years, there have been many inventions such as antibiotics, aeroplanes, and computers.

The part I'm particularly unclear about is; ‘**there have been many inventions such as**...’

Please explain which tense and voice this phrase is written in. When it is used, and its grammatical construction.

Comment: Please could you explain which part of the sentence you do not understand.

Comment: *There are (present simple), there were (past simple), there have been (present perfect), there had been (past perfect)* - all these are active voice forms. {GrammAr, not grammEr; prsent perfect continuous, not present perfect continuEs}

Comment: As you say, this is not continous, because there is no -ing. (As a side note, there is no such thing as "present perfect continues", and there is no such thing as "grammer". There is a present perfect continous, and grammar, respectively. Also, "shades" means "sunglasses". I wouldn't use a pair of those to clear doubts, if anything they make you see less clearly.)

Comment: @mahmudkoya    Thank you for correcting my spelling.

Comment: @WS2             The part I don't understand is,  ' there have been many inventions..'  what is the grammar rule here? Because 'Have been + verb-ING ' is what all I know. eg. They have been living here for six months. But there is no 'ing' here in the verb.

Comment: @everalian "They have been living here" contains the present perfect of the verb "to be" - "they have been". "Living" is not part of the verb, but a gerund noun, occupying the same place in the sentence as "many inventions". Some might argue that "they have been living here" is the present perfect continuous.

Comment: @WS2           Can you direct me to some sites? Because where ever I go, it's there only that have been + verb & ing.  What type of tense is this?

Comment: @everalian I'm afraid I don't know much about "sites". I'm just an old native speaker, guided by instinct.

Comment: @WS2            Can you tell me what is the verb in this sentence? "There have been many inventions such as TV and cars.

Comment: @everalian *...have been*. It is the present perfect of the verb "to be".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems the confusion here centers around the verb *to be*, which sometimes serves as an auxiliary verb and other times is the main verb.**

When it's an auxiliary verb, the main verb will follow. As you pointed out, *to be* is used in [passive voice](https://youtu.be/_PCCZ9Pvk2s) structures (in which case the main verb should be in the past participle form), and in continuous tenses (in which case the main verb should be in the present participle, or *-ing*, form).  However, in your example, we see no main verb that follows 'been'.

In any verb construction, the last word is the main verb while the rest are auxiliary verbs (or adverbs).  Your verb construction is "have been", so 'have' is the auxiliary verb and 'been' is the main verb.  **Since *to be* is not an auxiliary verb in this case, your sentence is neither passive nor continuous.**

In their comment, mahmud koya correctly identifies "have been" as present perfect (simple) in the active voice.  The present perfect uses 'have' before the main verb in the past participle form: 'been'.

In conclusion, it seems you considered *to be* only as an auxiliary verb, which left you wondering about the missing main verb.  But remember that *to be* isn't always an auxiliary verb, but can be the main verb, as it is in "there have been many inventions ..."  Therefore, **you have an active sentence in the present perfect tense.**

Comment: Yes. The confusion here was, unable to find the verb actually. Sometimes suddenly get confused with simple grammar also. Thank you all.